# amcharts gives unresponsive script message when maxSeries: 0

Tags: amcharts

I am building a chart using amcharts plugin, with candlestick type, the data is updated each minute, my client wanted not to group the date so I have used "maxSeries: 0" in the categoryAxesSettings configuration. Every thing works fine as long as we working with less than ~5000 but with more data growing day by day, it gives now "Unresponsive script" warning message.

```
panels: [{  
        stockGraphs: [{
            id: "g1",
            title: "Value",
            type: "candlestick",
            openField: "open",
            closeField: "close",
            highField: "high",
            lowField: "low",
            valueField: "close",
            lineColor: "#7f8da9",
            negativeLineColor: "#db4c3c",
            negativeFillColors: "#db4c3c",
            fillAlphas: 0.8,
            useDataSetColors: false,
            legendValueText: "Open:[[open]] Close:[[close]] Low:[[low]] High:[[high]] Volume:[[volume]]",
            showBalloon: true
        }],
        stockLegend: {
            useMarkerColorForValues: true,
            useMarkerColorForLabels: true,
            valueTextRegular: undefined,
            switchable: false,
            horizontalGap: 2,
            align: "left",
            reversedOrder: true,
            valueWidth: 150,
            markerType: "circle"
        },
        valueAxis: {
            gridColor: "#cccccc",
            gridAlpha: 1,
            showLastLabel: true
        }
    }
],
panelsSettings: {
    plotAreaFillColors: "#fff",
    plotAreaFillAlphas: 1,
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginTop: 5,
    marginBottom: 5
},

categoryAxesSettings: {
    parseDates: true,
    minPeriod: "mm",
    gridColor: "#cccccc",
    gridAlpha: 1,
    maxSeries: 0,
    groupToPeriods: ["30mm"]
},

chartCursorSettings: {
    valueLineEnabled:true,
    valueLineBalloonEnabled:true,
    valueBalloonsEnabled: true  
},

chartScrollbarSettings: {
    graph: "g1",
    graphType: "line",
    usePeriod: "30mm"
},

balloon: {
    textAlign: "left",
    offsetY: 10
},

periodSelector: {
    position: "bottom",
    dateFormat: "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
    periods: [{
        period: "mm",
        count: 30,
        label: "Minutes",
        selected:true
    }, {
        period: "hh",
        count: 12,
        label: "Hours",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "DD",
        count: 1,
        label: "1 day",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "DD",
        count: 10,
        label: "10 days",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "MM",
        count: 1,
        label: "1 month",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "MM",
        count: 6,
        label: "6 months",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "YYYY",
        count: 1,
        label: "1 year",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "YTD",
        label: "YTD",
        selected:false
    }, {
        period: "MAX",
        label: "MAX",
        selected:false
    }]
}
```

how could I ungroup the data without getting that warning message?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Data point grouping is there for the user experience as much as the performance. There is no way a user can comprehend 5000 data points crammed into 1000 pixels. I'm sure if you explain to the client what data point grouping is about, as well as work on setting grouping-specific settings, they will learn to appreciate it. There's really not a lot you can do to optimize performance of the large data sets without grouping, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you martynasma, I think you are right.